# How do I pause other processes when user input / confirmation is required Subprocess Python

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, wait

If I have a script (process run.py) that will run 3 subprocesses A.py, B.py, C.py (3 scripts called at same time through process run.py).

```
p= subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-u', 'A.py'])
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-u', 'B.py'])
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['python3', '-u', 'C.py'])
```

The operation is fine.
However say in b.py i have a line such as

```
reply = input( do you want to continue this action y/n :)
if reply.lower == 'yes':
take this action()
elif reply.lower == 'no' :
take other action()
```

(pref) How can i get subprocess of A.py and c.py to wait/pause for 5seconds, in order for user to enter y or no
or wait   in order for user to enter y or no

A basic confirm prompt in terminal. However the problem I face is A.py B.py running not allowing the confirmation which would start a different task/process/script.

Guidance here would be warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an external system to let the processes communicate between them.

The external system can be as simple as writing in a file some codes and having all the processes checking the state of the files.

B.py

```
with open("my.lock", "w") as f:
    f.write("a")
reply = input( do you want to continue this action y/n :)
if reply.lower == 'yes':
take this action()
elif reply.lower == 'no' :
take other action()
os.remove("my.lock")
```

A.py or C.py

```
import os
import time

while os.path.isfile("my.lock"):
   time.spleep(1)
# then your logic
```

A more sophisticated solution would be to have a message broker ([RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)...).

Comment: Do you have example, as I am trying to keep it simple as possible. whereby the processes run (concurrent) process B say encounters the code that requires response;  I would like to be able to input response, an have the other processes still running. (waiting/pausing may defeat the codes purpose) At the moment I am unable to input y or n in the terminal. Would a pop up work around this? so A.py & C.py work in the background, and I can confirm B.py allowing it to execute the confirmed process?

Comment: Just before the input() line, create a file named 'my.lock' (empty or with a single character). Remove this file after the user input the data. On the other side, at each loop of the other processes, check the file existance.

Comment: Check my last edit

Comment: Hi Sergio I will try to do what you have mentioned; however is there a way to answer/respond to B.py y/n confirmation while A.py and C.py continue running? I am thinking a new shell or popup may have to open in order to answer yes or no. Running A.py,B.py,C.py as individual programs they function as they should. Initially when B.py asked for confirmation it would throw EOFError, I bypasses the EOF using ececpt (e).

Comment: In the example i've written, A and C will be waiting while the lock file exits. The prompt will be stopped asking for a user input for B. For more details, you should share the code of A or C and the main thread, as I don't know how they interact.